# Transmission-cli installed through homebrew where is 'settings.json' located

Tags: homebrew, bittorrent, transmission, apple-m1, transmission-daemon

I've installed `transmission-cli` through homebrew (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/transmission-cli)
I cannot find `settings.json`, I want to run a script to send a notification/mail on completion of the torrent

Answer (score 0):

When installed through homebrew the `settings.json` is located in `~/Library/Application Support/transmission-daemon/`

credits: https://helpful.wiki/transmission